# Plane to circle get "pinched" corners

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to figure out a way to make the ellipse shape even, right now the inner elliptical shape is even all the way around except in the corners where the shape get skinnier. is there a way to make all faces of that inner shape even?

here's images of my problem [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't see any other solution than delete the inner ellipse and re-extrude inwards, bevel, etc.

If you want to redo this kind of shape from scratch, here are several ways to do it, the less destructive would be with a curve, but if you begin with a mesh you can now custom the profile:

- Create your ellipse object, select the top edge:

[image]

- Bevel it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, give it enough segments:

[image]

- Enable the *Custom* option and draw your profile:

[image]

[image]

A similar custom profile has also been implemented for the curves, go in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry > Bevel* and click on *Profile*:

[image]

You will have much more control on the bevel shape if you use the *Object* option though:

[image]

Or of course you can use a mesh as a profile along a curve with the *Array* and *Curve* modifiers:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @moonboots  started out by making a plane, subdivided a few times and converted the square shape to a circle which I scaled on the X axes to make the circle an ellipse. then I modeled the the shape form there. the custom bevel function was not an option when I designed this (blender 2.80 I believe) Is there a way where I can make the faces have even width without starting over?

Comment: you can delete all the part that is not even, select the new inner ellipse and extrude inwards

Comment: Thank you again, I think that might be the best solution.

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to start from scratch I don't see another solution but maybe someone has a better one...