# How to bend painting frame sections in hollow?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am modeling a  picture frame. I would like to have a rounded profile instead of a straight one.
I divided  faces than I want to bend with loop cut tool. but I have no idea.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom bevel profile.

I started with a cube, inset the front and back face, and bridged the edge loops to create a frame.

[image]

Select one edge loop and create a bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

Once you create a bevel, you can open the panel in the bottom left to modify your last action.  Bump up the number of segments and select Custom profile.  You can model your bevel using the curve provided.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a right angle and bevel it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (the options are in the *Operator* box):

[image]

[image]

If you have already given your angle a bevel like this one:

[image]

You can select a central edge, enable the *Proportional Editing* option, choose its *Smooth* falloff option, make sure that the radius is small enough (mouse scroll wheel) and move the edge on the X axis:

[image]

[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202124/plane-to-circle-get-pinched-corners/202128#202128) I give an answer that might also help for this kind of object.

Comment: "You could move one of your edge loops with the Proportional Editing option enabled" I need more help for this solution

Comment: I select a loop with edges selected and o shortcut

Comment: please share your current file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I did it. You will find the link on my post

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it's clear

Comment: clear but not for me. After loop cut. I select a central edge, I click on the circle on the top of the 3D view for proportionnal editing but it is all the frame that is moving !

Comment: yes because the influence radius is too high, you need to reduce it with the scroll wheel, when it will be small enough you'll see the radius circle

Comment: check here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/change-radius-for-proportional-editing#:~:text=You%20must%20press%20PgUp%20PgDown,%2C%20or%20Scale%20(%20S%20).&text=In%20the%20Redo%20panel%20located,to%20adjust%20the%20Proportional%20size.