# How to model this profile?

Tags: modeling

I just want to know how you go about creating the rounded profile along the top of this wall. I have tried but don't know how to make it.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for *Bevel Modifier* with a custom profile

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edi

Answer (score 0):

Select the edge you want and give a Bevel Weight to it (edge should turn blue).  Then use a *Bevel Modifier* set to weight, increase the number of segments and activate a custom profile.

I'm on my phone, so unable to edit quickly, but here's another post where I use an actual bevel to achieve the same.  Either method should work pretty much the same, the modifier is non-destructive, though.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/202897/110840